# How I can make chess-timer clock in android

Tags: android

I am a beginner in android, and I want to make a simple chess-timer clock. Here, I have taken two buttons. If I click on the first one the second button should start a countdown or vice-versa. But pause button is not working properly it pauses only one time second time it will not pause. Here I attached my code.

```
package com.example.jaydeep.practicework.chessClock;

import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.jaydeep.practicework.R;

public class Main8Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button button11,button22;
    CountDownTimer count,count1;
    int s1=60,s2=60;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main8);
        button11 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button11);
        button22 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button22);

        button11.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                button11.setEnabled(false);
                    reverseTimer1(s2, button22);
            }
        });
        button22.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               button22.setEnabled(false);
                    reverseTimer(s1, button11);
            }
        });
    }

    public void reverseTimer(int Seconds,final Button button){
        button11.setEnabled(true);
     count= new CountDownTimer(Seconds* 1000+1000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                int seconds = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                s1=seconds;
                int minutes = seconds / 60;
                seconds = seconds % 60;
                button.setText( String.format("%02d", minutes)
                        + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds));
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                button.setText("Time Up!!!");
            }
        };
        count.start();
    }
    public void reverseTimer1(int Seconds,final Button button){
        button22.setEnabled(true);
        count1= new CountDownTimer(Seconds* 1000+1000, 1000) {

                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        int seconds = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                        s2=seconds;
                        int minutes = seconds / 60;
                        seconds = seconds % 60;
                        button.setText( String.format("%02d", minutes)
                                + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds));
                    }

                    public void onFinish() {
                        button.setText("Time Up!!!");
                    }
                };
        count1.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please improve text formatting of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   cancel();
```

You need this code

```
 if(isPaused || isCanceled)
                        {
                            //If the user request to cancel or paused the
                            //CountDownTimer we will cancel the current instance
                            cancel();
                        }
```

This link should help you understand:
https://android--examples.blogspot.com.au/2015/04/android-countdowntimer-start-pause.html